# click jquery não funciona no firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, click

Bom dia, após o código que preenche a tabela, a manipulação do click não funciona no firefox, mas funciona no chrome, alguém tem alguma luz, por favor?

```
function carregarItens(){


//variáveis
var itens = "", url = "transfer.php";

//Capturar Dados Usando Método AJAX do jQuery
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {
        //$("h2").html("Carregando..."); //Carregando
    },
    error: function() {
      //  $("h2").html("Há algum problema com a fonte de dados");
    },
    success: function(retorno) {
        if(retorno[0].erro){
           // $("h2").html(retorno[0].erro);
        }
        else{
            //Laço para criar linhas da tabela
            for(var i = 0; i<retorno.length; i++){
                itens += "<tr>";
                itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].idusuario + "</td>";
                itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].desLogin + "</td>";
                itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].dessenha + "</td>";
                itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].dtcadastro + "</td>";
                itens += "</tr>";
            }
            //Preencher a Tabela
            $('.table tbody').html(itens);



            //Limpar Status de Carregando
          //  $("h2").html("Carregado");
        }
    }
});

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#clicked tr").on('click', function(){
                    alert('adfsaf');
                });
            });
```

}

Comment: Apresenta algum erro no console?

Comment: aparece isso: jquery.min.js (linha 4), mas funciona no chrome

Comment: `#clicked` é o quê? Se usares `$("#clicked").on('click', 'tr', function(){` já funciona?

Comment: #clicked é o id do elemento <tbody> da minha tabela, mas sua dica já resolveu meu problema, muito obrigado aí cara